# How to perform arithmetics on element in 2D Numpy array involving elements indices?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

**Context**

I am implementing 2D Discrete Fourier Transform algorithm using Python with Numpy.
According to image processing theory in order to center image's transform, before performing the transform, each intensity f(x, y) of the image needs to be multiplied by (-1)^(x + y) where x and y are intensity's indices in 2D array representing the image.

**What was tried**

The obvious approach is to iterate over each intensity and its indices using two for loops.

**Question**

Is there a more elegant/faster solution using Python/Numpy matrix operations or should I stick with two for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
y,x = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
prefactor = (-1)**(y+x)
```

Here `m,n` are, of course, the dimensions of your operand array.